# Mongo repository query introducing field value from method parameter

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, mongorepository

I am trying to look for all the objects inside a Mongodb collection that have the same identification in `"jugador"` field which is inside the `"jugada"` object in the collection `"jugadas"`.

For that, I have created a method in the interface that implements mongorepository in spring boot with the following syntax:

```java
public interface JugadaRepository extends MongoRepository<Jugada, String> {
    @Query("{ 'jugador' : {'$oid' : : #{#jugador_id}}")
    List<Jugada> findAllByJugador_id(@Param("jugador_id") String jugador_id);
}
```

When I substitute the `#{#jugador_id}}`  by any `jugadorid` string like this:

```
@Query("{ 'jugador' : {'$oid' : '644aa4b99363b30d6b21fc6f'}}")
```

... it works without problem, giving all the files `"jugadas"` that have that string in their `"jugador"` `"_id"` fields.

I think the syntax of the interface method query is correct by I don't know enough about mongoDB to be totally sure.

Could you help me in  finding out if it is a syntax problem or another issue here?